# kivymd packaging Problem with pyinstaller

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, kivymd

I have a heavy kivymd project developed by lazy loading method (with a template similar to [this project](https://github.com/Kulothungan16/kivy-lazy-loading-template) but much bigger with many screens and libraries).
which works well and without any problems in pycharm. I tried to get windows output using pyinstaller but I got the following error(it returned many warnings but this was the last error):

> Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_kivy actually exists
> and whether the hook is compatible with your version of
> C:UsersAchillesPycharmProjectsPandasvenvlibsite-packagesPyInstallerhookshook-kivy.py

by:

kivy==2.0.0 kivymd==0.104.2 pyinstaller==5.4.1 python==3.9

then i tried change pyinstaller version to **4.5.1** and try again. This time it still returned a few warnings, but it didn't stop and managed to get at least one output from the project.

Here the next problem started, by running the exe file, every time it returns an error stating that one of the libraries used in the software is not recognized.

First time:

> No module named 'plyer'

second time:

```
[ERROR  ] Traceback (most recent call last):   File "kivy\lang\parser.py", line 472, in execute_directives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd_extensions'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "kivy\lang\parser.py", line 474, in execute_directives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd_extensions' [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress... Parser: File "C:\Users\Achilles\Desktop\hamta_v1\dist\hamta\View\LoginScreen\login_screen.kv", line 3: ...
      1:#:import arabic_reshaper arabic_reshaper
      2:#:import get_display bidi.algorithm.get_display
      3:#:import AKSpinnerFoldingCube kivymd_extensions.akivymd.uix.spinners.AKSpinnerFoldingCube
      4:
      5: ... Unable to import package 'kivymd_extensions.akivymd.uix.spinners.AKSpinnerFoldingCube'
```

And the following, pandas, pytz, dateutil, uuid and ...
every time I added these libraries to the datas in the .spec file in this way:

```
site_packages_dir =
'C:\\Users\\Achilles\\PycharmProjects\\hamta_software\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\'

datas=[(site_packages_dir+'plyer', './plyer'),(site_packages_dir+'kivymd_extensions', './kivymd_extensions'),(site_packages_dir+'pandas', './pandas'), (site_packages_dir+'pytz','./pytz'), (site_packages_dir+'dateutil', './dateutil')],
```

but every time it did not find another library and it is definitely unusual because, for example, the plyer library is not a hidden import.